# Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException codechef

Tags: java

I am trying to read into an integer variable in Codechef IDE(https://www.codechef.com/ide) using java  and getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
at CleanUp.main(Main.java:8)
```

Following is my code

```
import java.util.*;

class CleanUp {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
     Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
     int T;
     T = sc.nextInt();
     System.out.println(T);

 }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `Custom Input` checkbox under the text area where you can write your code. You need to check it and write your number inside the text area that appeared. But I would suggest to not use online IDEs (they're considerably slower).

[image]